# consulta e alteração de procedures para camada DAO C#

Tags: c#

inclusão, alteração, obtenção

Foi criada diversas procedures com a finalidade de inclusão, alteração, consulta, obtenção de dados etc.
As procedures foram criadas no SQL Server 2014. Preciso acessar essas procedures via conexão banco utilizando C# no Visual Studio. 
Foi criada uma camada DAO, sendo declarado todos os metodos para acesso as essas procedures. Os metodos estao vazios... 
MInha dúvida é quanto a estruturação da conexão, comandos e adição de parametros em codigo.

Por exemplo, para a procedure STP_INS_MvtoContasAdtoDevol fiz o seguinte codigo:

```
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "STP_INS_MvtoContasAdtoDevol";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_ENC_Id", Integer).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_Meio_Recebto", varchar(30)).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_Adquirente", varchar(30)).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_TIP_ID_Dev", Integer).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_FIL_Id", Integer).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_TIP_Sigla", Char(3)).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_DthMovto", SmallDateTime).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_VlrMovto", Decimal(14,2)).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_QtdeParcelas", Integer).Value = "0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MAD_Obs", varchar(500)).Value = "0";

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

coloquei 0. alguem poderia me ajudar pois tambem preciso fazer referencia a objetos preenchendo esses dados?
ps.: essa seria estrutura para inclusao, nao sei se esta certa. como ficaria para consulta, alteração etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mariana,
Para isolar  na camada DAO implemente os metodos apenas de manipulação segue um  de uma projeto tipo dll onde tem um metodo conexão adiciona parametros, Executa manipulação para chamar as procedures, também executa consulta exemplo :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DAL.Properties;

namespace DAL
{
  public class Acesso{

   private SqlConnection Conexao()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.stringCoxecao);
    }


    private SqlParameterCollection sqlParameterCollection = new SqlCommand().Parameters;

    public void LimparParametros()
    {
        sqlParameterCollection.Clear();
    }

    public void AdicionarParametos(string nomeParametro, object valorParametro)
    {
        sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter(nomeParametro,valorParametro));
    }

    public object ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType commandType, string StoreProcedureOuTexto)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = Conexao();
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = StoreProcedureOuTexto;
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

            foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value));
            }
            return sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public DataTable ExecutaConsulta(CommandType commandType, string StoradeProcedureOuTText)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = Conexao();
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = StoradeProcedureOuTText;
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

            foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value));
            }

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return  dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {

            throw new  Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

No projeto eu criei outra camada chamada de DTO(objeto de transferencia) e uma camada chamada BLL. Como o projeto era simples fazia um cadastro clientes na DTO tinha as classe cliente e cliente coleção
classe cliente

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DTO
{
   public  class Cliente
{
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public Boolean Sexo { get; set; }
    public decimal LimiteDeCompra { get; set; }
}
}
```

Classe clientecolecao

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace DTO
 {
     public class ClienteColecao : List<Cliente>
    {
    }
 }
```

Apos isso na camada BLL utilizava essa duas camadas segue código da camada BLL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

using DAL;
using DTO;

namespace BLL
{
    public class ClienteBLL
{
    Acesso acesso = new Acesso();

      public string Inserir(Cliente cliente)
      {
         try
        {
            acesso.LimparParametros();
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@Nome", cliente.Nome);
              acesso.AdicionarParametos("DataNascimento",cliente.DataNascimento);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@Sexo", cliente.Sexo);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("LimiteCompra", cliente.LimiteDeCompra);
            string idCliente = acesso.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spInserir").ToString();

            return idCliente;

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            return exception.Message;
        }

    }

    public string Alterar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        try
        {
            acesso.LimparParametros();
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@ID", cliente.IdCliente);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@Nome", cliente.Nome);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@DataNascimento", cliente.DataNascimento);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@Sexo", cliente.Sexo);
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@LimiteCompra", cliente.LimiteDeCompra);

            string Idcliente = acesso.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spAlterar").ToString();

            return Idcliente;
        }
        catch (Exception excepcion)
        {

            return excepcion.Message;
        }

    }

    public string Excluir(Cliente cliente)
    {

        try
        {
            acesso.LimparParametros();
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@ID", cliente.IdCliente);
            string IdCliente = acesso.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spExcluir").ToString();

            return IdCliente;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           return ex.Message;
        }

    }

    public ClienteColecao ConsultaPorNome(string nome)
    {

        try
        {
            ClienteColecao clientCollect = new ClienteColecao();

            acesso.LimparParametros();
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@Nome", nome);
            DataTable dataTableCli = acesso.ExecutaConsulta(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spConsultaNome");

            foreach (DataRow linha in dataTableCli.Rows)
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(linha["Id"]);
                cliente.Nome = Convert.ToString(linha["Nome"]);
                cliente.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(linha["DataNascimento"]);
                cliente.Sexo = Convert.ToBoolean(linha["Sexo"]);
                cliente.LimiteDeCompra = Convert.ToDecimal(linha["LimiteCompra"]);

                clientCollect.Add(cliente);
            }

            return clientCollect;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Não foi possivel consultar o cliente por nome. Detalhes:  "+ ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public ClienteColecao ConsultaPorId(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            ClienteColecao clientCollect = new ClienteColecao();

            acesso.LimparParametros();
            acesso.AdicionarParametos("@ID", id);
            DataTable dataTableCli = acesso.ExecutaConsulta(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spConsultaNome");

            foreach (DataRow linha in dataTableCli.Rows)
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(linha["Id"]);
                cliente.Nome = Convert.ToString(linha["Nome"]);
                cliente.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(linha["DataNascimento"]);
                cliente.Sexo = Convert.ToBoolean(linha["Sexo"]);
                cliente.LimiteDeCompra = Convert.ToDecimal(linha["LimiteCompra"]);

                clientCollect.Add(cliente);
            }

            return clientCollect;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Não foi possivel consultar o cliente por nome. Detalhes:  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Se tiver alguma duvida quanto o código posta nos comentários!

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de [Arquitetura BOLOVO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCC_RS0WXHw) separando a aplicação por "nívels" como *view/business/data* é muito ruim e ultrapassada. Já foi muito utilizada, mas os profissionais já enxergaram que é uma abordagem com mais desvantagens que vantagens.

Sua pergunta foi sobre como chamar `StoredProcedures` passando valores, tudo certinho. Pois bem, você pode simplicar bem essa parte do código:

Leia a documentação do [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx): Voce pode fazer algo simples como `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MAD_ENC_Id", value));` que vai funcionar.